# How can user designate/set monitor number?

Tags: display

Assume user with macbook main display and 2 external monitors.
Screenshots (Cmd+Sh+3)are tagged with monitor number. (2) and (3) are appended.

If user changes number of external monitors (sometimes 2, other times 3) - MacOS names/numbers the monitors willy nilly. That is not ideal.

How can a user change or "control" the order/naming (retina laptop display be always "1"?